# Kubernetes Cluster Federation retired?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have come across a need that I need to serve application users based on their geo-location.
One possibility, I could think of it to have application installed on multiple k8s clusters hosted in different region and then load-balance the traffic based on geo-location of the users.

While exploring this idea, I came across several articles on "Kubernetes Cluster Federation" (e.g. https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/10/globally-distributed-services-kubernetes-cluster-federation/). But seems like this functionality has been retired as mentioned in https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/federation.

Does someone know:

1. If there is any alternative for "Kubernetes Cluster Federation"?
2. Is there any other solution/s to address the need of serving users based on their geo-location?
3. If we leave the application part, is there any way to store the data in same geo-location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubefed is a successor to the "Kubernetes Cluster Federation", though I am not sure what is its current state. If you want to deploy a global loadbalancer, I suggest to have a look into https://www.k8gb.io/ .

Answer (score 0):

`...k8s clusters hosted in different region and then load-balance the traffic based on geo-location of the users`

If you determine the user location simply by the network location, you can use DNS geolocation routing capability such as [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/geolocation-routing-policy/) to reach nearest services. In this context k8s federation is not required.

`If we leave the application part, is there any way to store the data in same geo-location?`

Apart from global scale database solution such as Aurora, Spanner, your application can point to a centralize database that resides in one of the region; if the increase latency is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry, I was not very clear in my question "If we leave the application part, is there any way to store the data in same geo-location as the user?" And for "If you determine the user location simply by the network location, you can use DNS geolocation routing capability such as Route 53 to reach nearest services. In this context k8s federation is not required.", does it mean that I need to think about 2 separate k8s clusters, if that is the case I was looking for some solution for multi cluster management.

Comment: There is no short of centralize cluster management tools like kubesphere, Rancher etc if you really need it. With or without this the suggestions in the answer can still apply.